# ASP.Net how to auto start the Application without user first request to the server?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications

I have some scheduled jobs that need to be run in the Application_Start but as far as I know, this method only get triggered after the first request. Is there anyway I can just auto startup the application after I stop and start the connection in IIS or stop/start/restart the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on IIS 7.5, you can setup the application auto start, as you can see on this [post on the ScottGu blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx).

Basically, you have to add the `startMode=”AlwaysRunning”` attribute on the application host config file, in the app worker process entry.

Comment: well, I don't use IIS 7.5 so is there any other way? appreciate your help though

Comment: The only other way occurs to me is to use a windows service that recalls an empty page of the application every some minutes, but is *very* ugly. Which schedule job are you going to run in Application_Start? Why do you need to run it inside the web app?

Comment: I have a routine check every 2 minutes to check for client dead or alive, if it's dead then send out an alert email to admin, and also a routine export data to a ftp server every 30 minutes

Comment: Scott's blog is out of date as it doesn't mention that the feature was removed from IIS 7.5 but its available as a downloadable module - info and link here http://serverfault.com/questions/373548/warming-up-an-iis-application-pool-automatically A UI is available here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amol/archive/2013/01/25/application-initialization-ui-for-iis-7-5.aspx

Answer (score 5):

**I. Install the Application Initialization Module**
The application initialization module allows IIS to preemptively perform initialization tasks such as making the initial HTTP request to your application, or call your custom logic to perform whatever you desire to warm up your app.
I find it necessary to install the module even though  the settings for making an application auto start and always running are there on IIS 10 which is the server I am using.
You can install the Application Initialization module via the Server Manager.

You can find the module under Server Roles -> Web Server -> Application Developer -> Application Initialization.

**II. Configure the app pool**
In IIS Manager, right click on the application pool under which the application runs and select “Advanced Settings”. Update the following values:
•   Set the .NET CLR version to v4.0.
•   Set start mode to “Always
Running”.
•   Set Idle Time-Out (minutes) to 0.

**III. Configure the IIS site**
In IIS Manager, right click on the site for the application, select “Manage Website” -> “Advanced Settings” and set the “Preload Enabled” value to true.

Comment: This answer is correct. The accepted answer is not.