# ASP.NET 5 Non-Controller DI injection

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to use the new `ASP.NET 5` dependency injection system, but it seems limited to ONLY constructors of classes that inherit from `Controller`.

Is there any other way to inject things? Properties? Anything? This is so severely limiting and has had me brickwalling for days.

Comment: that is not true at all, any class with a constructor can easily registered with DI and injected wherever they are needed so long as all the types needed by the constructor are also registered in DI. each dependency in the chain must be registered with DI. what makes you think it is limited to controllers?

Comment: 1) I can't find any examples otherwise. 2) I don't understand how the class gets instantiated then. What creates it?

Comment: I would be greatly in your debt if you could show me an example of how this works on other classes. I'm just not "getting" it. It is driving me up a wall of crazy.

Comment: The major thing I can't figure out is how another class could get created.

Comment: @Ciel: You should include the code example which demonstrates what you want to implement, especially **which relation have the code with the HTTP requests**, which come from clients of ASP.NET application. It's important that DI allows to extend `HttpContext` created on the new HTTP request. It contains `RequestServices` property (`HttpContext.RequestServices`) of the type `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider`. One can write controller action, exception handle, compression module etc which get custom information from `HttpContext.RequestServices`, but in a comfortable way.

Comment: I think if you read [question and answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32599573/how-do-i-inject-asp-net-5-vnext-user-secrets-into-my-own-utility-class/32608820#32608820) as well as the discussion in comments it will help you

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the behavior I want is. I just know that I've got some dependencies that I really need to be in a service, non-controller class and I'm trying to figure out how to do it without just instantiating it with a dependency in a controller. I'm looking over this question you linked, and I'm not clear how they are related.

Comment: I'm very lost. You still leave out the main thing I'm having trouble with in your other post; How to instantiate the object. I just don't get it, I'm sorry. What MAKES the object and injects it?

Comment: In that example, yeah.. if you can get `MailMaker` to be created by something, great - dependencies. But that's where I'm so lost. What makes it? You can't just call `new MailMaker`, otherwise you would just do it. Is there some kind of activator or something?

Comment: I'm sorry if I seem rushed. I'm just very frustrated with this whole thing.

Comment: Is there no way to do it if the class being created doesn't exist anywhere near an `HttpContext`?

Comment: @JoeAudette pasting my response below here, too. Alright... I'm looking back at this after having some time to sober up and WOW. I wasn't thinking straight at all. Thanks so much for putting up with me. I think the question I'm really asking is _"How do I get an instance of the service locator or activator to instantiate a class outside a web request? "_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested this (RC1 Update1), it works with other classes as well.
I wrote a small example, first the type declarations:

```cs
public interface IBaseServiceType { }

public interface IComposedServiceType
{
    IBaseServiceType baseService { get; }
}

public class BaseServiceImplementation : IBaseServiceType { }

public class ComposedServiceImplementation : IComposedServiceType
{
    public IBaseServiceType baseService { private set; get; }

    public ComposedServiceImplementation(IBaseServiceType baseService)
    {
        this.baseService = baseService;
    }
}
```

The configuration:

```cs
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IBaseServiceType), typeof(BaseServiceImplementation));
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IComposedServiceType), typeof(ComposedServiceImplementation));
```

And create the instance like this where `context` is your `HttpContext`:

```cs
 var composedServiceInstance = context.ApplicationServices.GetService<IComposedServiceType>();
```

Comment: Is it possible to get it even if you don't have an `HttpContext`?

Comment: @Ciel: sure, you only need a reference to the `IServiceProvider` instance.

Comment: Hrnm.. I'm trying to think of how to get that. Basically, I have a class that needs to run, but it isn't inside a Controller and it doesn't get an HttpContext at all.

Comment: you will have to make a decision **_when_** your "*class needs to run*".

Comment: @Ciel: basically you have two options to pass data: using the stack or static members. static members can be accessed without an instance.

Comment: Alright... I'm looking back at this after having some time to sober up and WOW. I wasn't thinking straight at all. Thanks so much for putting up with me. I think the question I'm really asking is _"How do I get an instance of the service locator or activator to instantiate a class outside a web request? "_

Comment: That depends on from where your code would be called. As long as no code is run, you simply cannot. For example, the runtime serves you an instance of `IServiceProvider` via the `IApplicationBuilder` argument when it calls the `Configure` method on the instance of the Startup class.

Comment: So it's `HttpContext` or Singleton, huh? That means it wouldn't even be possible to use this DI in a non-web app, would it?

Comment: What prevents you from using this DI via the `IApplicationBuilder` instance from the `Configure` method in your *non-web app*?

Comment: @Ciel: sorry, I misunderstood the question in your earlier comment. Just call your code from the `Configure` method in your startup class. There you can use DI via the `ApplicationServices` member of the `IApplicationBuilder` instance given by the runtime. Keep in mind though to configure your host accordingly to **not** wait for a request to start the application (as this is default for some popular hosts like IIS). In case you use IIS see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4333535/1698246

Answer (score 0):

Register your class as a service and treat it like you would all other services

see 
[Net Core Dependency Injection for Non-Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41614194/net-core-dependency-injection-for-non-controller/45124407#45124407)