# Global.asax acting like Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a problem where code that exists in global.asax and application_start only triggers when opening the site in a browser, similar to what you'd expect startup.cs to do.

How do I cause the methods in global.asax to trigger on iis startup?

Edit: ApplicationHosts.config is configured correctly with "AlwaysRunning". The server still only starts its background processes only on page load. I'm using Hangfire to manage the processes, and hangfire is initiated via global.asax and another file in application_start that global.asax calls that enqueues the actual processes in hangfire.

Comment: Neither `Global.asax` or `Startup.cs` are being triggered. It's the *methods* defined in it that getting triggered during the life cycle of the application/request.

Comment: Global.asax starts when the web application starts, no matter the stack. Startup.cs is called by Global.asax. You are asking a very different question - how to start the web application with IIS, not when the first request comes

Comment: To expand on Panagiotis answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333128/asp-net-how-to-auto-start-the-application-without-user-first-request-to-the-serv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net how to auto start the Application without user first request to the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333128/asp-net-how-to-auto-start-the-application-without-user-first-request-to-the-serv)

Comment: If you want a service-like behaviour of your web application, you should also look at the IIS parameters for shutting down the application after x minutes (usually 20 minutes, if I recall that correctly).

Comment: You could use the warmup module, that might be the easiest solution